# train and test split using R for user based collaborative filtering

Tags: r, cosine-similarity, collaborative-filtering, recommendation-engine

I am stuck with User based CF. I am trying to predict ratings for the users. I have used cosine similarity and found the user similarity matrix with the original ratings. What would be the next steps in predicting the user ratings? How can I achieve that using R code? Please advise.
final data is my data set with users in rows and movie ID's in the columns they have rated. Now my challenge is how do I predict the ratings?

Sample Input data:

[image: Sample Input data]

Sample Output data:

[image: Sample output data]

```
cosine_sim <- function(a, b){crossprod(a, b) / sqrt(crossprod(a) * crossprod(b))}
user_similarities <- matrix(0, nrow = 10000, ncol = 10000)
for (i in 1:9999) {
for (j in (i + 1):10000) {
user_similarities[i,j] <- cosine_sim(final_data3[i,], final_data3[j,])
}
}
user_similarities <- user_similarities + t(user_similarities)
diag(user_similarities) <- 0
row.names(user_similarities) <- row.names(final_data3)
colnames(user_similarities) <- row.names(final_data3)
round(user_similarities, 3)
```

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(final_data3)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(final_data3, 20))`.

Comment: I have added Rui, thank you for responding

Comment: Images are a bad way of posting data, please post the output of `dput(final_data3[1:20, 1:20])`, not an image. The indices are meant to keep the posted data relatively small.